# Having numbers generated in for loop how to output them as if their highest value was 1 and lowest 0?

Tags: c++, c, boost, opencv, normalization

So I have a black and white image in OpenCV, currently I output each of its per pixel color values into file so I get a file of values from 1 to 255. I have lots of really small images so in one image I usually get values that have small difference. like from 25 to 100.. So I need a way to print into file not color values but values from 0 to 1 where lowest color would be 0 and highest 1...

```
for(x=0;x<w;x++){
     for(y=0;y<h;y++){
          double RealColor = cvGetReal2D(source, y, x);
          file << RealColor << " ";
     }
     file << endl;
}file << endl;
```

How to do such a thing?

Comment: 272 questions asked on SO and you *still* haven't learned to format code properly ???

Comment: I don't know if that last output is to be there, so I left it. Presumably it shouldn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do a first pass, and find minimum and maximum values.  Then do a second pass, and modify each value as `(v - min) / (max - min)` before writing to file.

Comment: how do you search for min-max values in my situation?

Comment: @Kab: There is `std::min_element` and `std::max_element` in the `<algorithm>` header.

Comment: hm... I tried.. it works some how badly... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918437/how-to-make-such-construction-return-values-form-0-to-1

Answer (score 1):

This is better (OpenCV just have function to normalize between 0 and 1):

```
cvNormalize(source,source,1,0,CV_MINMAX );
```

Comment: your solution would just output 1s and 0s like 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0  while I WOULD LIVE TO SEE 0, 0.1 , 0.11 ... 1=)

Comment: No. My solution puts out float 32bit from 0 to 1 if source is 32bit float. I am sure: I am using it in my project.