# How to make such construction return values form 0 to 1?

Tags: c++, floating-point, int, double

It give me only 1s

```
        int maxVal;
        int minVal;
        int wh = w*h;
        int values[1000];
        for(x=0;x<w;x++){
            for(y=0;y<h;y++){
                double RealColor = cvGetReal2D(source, y, x);
                values[x*y + y] = RealColor; 
            }
        }
        minVal = *min_element(values,(values+wh));
        maxVal = *max_element(values,(values+wh));
        float dif = maxVal - minVal;
        float fminVal;
        fminVal = minVal;
        for(x=0;x<w;x++){
            for(y=0;y<h;y++){
                float rc = cvGetReal2D(source, y, x);
                float normRealColor =(rc - fminVal + 1) / dif;
                file << normRealColor << " ";
            }
            file << endl;
        }file << endl;
```

How to make it to return not only 1 or 0 but 0, 0.1 0.001 ... 1 HOW??? *wall*

Comment: Did you try using a debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `values` array is an array of `int`, so it can only contain integers rather than floating-point numbers.  Does changing it to `float` or `double` fix the problem?  Also, your indexing expression `x*y + y` is incorrect: it should be `x*h + y` or `w*y + x`.